# “select_for_update” called inside an atomic block still TransactionManagementError

Tags: django, django-orm

The code blow

```
@transaction.atomic
def cancel_one(o_id):
    order= Order.objects.select_for_update().get(id=o_id)
```

raises

> TransactionManagementError('select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.')
>
> django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.

I have checked my code is in transaction by `transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block.`

It appeared in the transaction, but still raises

> Error: django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.

My Code:

```
# Step1
def cancel_one(o_id):
   print("DO")
   cxn = transaction.get_connection()
   if cxn.in_atomic_block:
       print("We're inside a transaction!")
   order= Order.objects.select_for_update().get(id=o_id)

# Step2
@transaction.atomic
def cancel_one(o_id):
   print("DO")
   cxn = transaction.get_connection()
   if cxn.in_atomic_block:
       print("We're inside a transaction!")
   order= Order.objects.select_for_update().get(id=o_id)
```

Code Result

```
# Step1
-----------------------
DO
-----------------------

# Step2
-----------------------
DO
"We're inside a transaction!"
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 11):

Are you using DBRouters by any chance? I had trouble with this - trick was to define the DB on the transaction AND select_for_update

```
with transaction.atomic(using='db_x'):
    order = Order.objects.using('db_x').select_for_update().get(id=o_id)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this wouldn't work when a DB router is being used?

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a lot of head scratching. Note that if you save an object you might also have to specify `order.save(using='db_x')` too.

Comment: @codeara If using DBRouters with seperate DBs for reads and writes, I assume Django is setting the transaction on the Write DB instance, and the select for update on the Read DB instance - which would explain the error returned on the OPs post.